# register GSM operator in android programatically

Tags: android

How to register with another GSM Operator in android ?

Suppose my current GSM network provider is `IDEA` and now I want to register with `AIRTEL` Operator ,then how can i do it,with the help of code?

Comment: what do you mean by this "How to other registered GSM Operator in android "? please frame your question properly

Comment: Explain.... what you are trying to do... and one more thing its does not depend on Ides or Airtel or VODAPHONE

Comment: @Goofy please check my update question i hope now you will understand

Comment: As far as I know, you can't. The [TelephonyManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html) allows you to get information about the network you're on, but not to change it.

Comment: Can you even do this manually, without changing the sim?  Or do you have some sort of dual-sim device or post-sim variation of gsm?

Comment: @ChrisStratton yes i want to  do this without changing sim in single sim device

Comment: But can you even do that from settings menus?  Normally when someone says they want to do something "programatically" on Android, they are talking about trying to let an app do what a user can do from a settings menu.  But it's not clear if what you want to do is supported even by the settings menus.

Comment: @ChrisStratton i dont want to open any setting menu can you just suggest me how to get list of neigbhourcell info because  List<NeighboringCellInfo> neighbours = telManager.getNeighboringCellInfo();its return empty list

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to perform this task explicitly {No Permissions}, unless bypassing the Android kernal and coding explicitly.

Comment: Right idea, wrong details.  The kernel has little to do with it.

Comment: hey, this is not fair. could have acknowledged the idea and I haven't given any details, since I am not aware of that....